# CompositeFuture not working with Futures returning Lists

Tags: java, vert.x

I have a specific use case for data processing where I am returning a future of type `Future<List<SamplePOJO>>`. I have multiple such futures which I am adding to a List.

But `CompositeFuture.join()` doesn't work on this list as it is asking for a `List<Future>` instead of a `List<Future<List<SamplePOJO>>>`. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can collect all those `Future<List<SamplePOJO>>` in the `List<Future>` instead of `List<Future<List<SamplePOJO>>>`.

That will make `CompositeFuture.all` method accept it.

```java
        Future<List<String>> f = getFuture();
        
        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        futures.add(f);
        
        CompositeFuture.all(futures);
```

Comment: I tried that. But then I get an Object instead of a List when I do future.result() on the futures inside that list.

Comment: The reason why `CompositeFuture.all` accepts non parameterized `Future` is so that you can pass it a list of futures that possibly resolve to different result types. That could not be handled with generic (though it could probably accept a list of `Future<?>` instead of just `Future`). It seems that the only solution is to have one `List<Future<List<SamplePOJO>>>` that you'll later use to fetch results from and then second list (with copied elements) of type `List<Future>` that you pass to `CompositeFuture.all`.

Comment: Ah okay. This sounds a bit complex. I'll see if I can implement an alternative approach which is simpler. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expanded set of example code (that I mistakenly wrote for another question and moved here).

So there exists [a bug in Vert.x](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/4384) that causes issues with `CompositeFuture.all(listoffutures)`, etc., at least in JDK 17, if `listoffutures` is of type `List<Future<SomeType>>` (or `List<Future<?>>`).

This bug might get fixed in Vert.x 5.

I got some success with the code below.  The contrived example here is that I want to turn a `List<Future<File>>` into a `Future<List<File>>`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
static List<Future> ltol(List<Future<File>> sa) {
  List<Future> l = new ArrayList<>();
  l.addAll(sa);
  return l;
}


// A contrived example of what I was doing, which uses .compose and returns
// a Future of the list of results (File objects in my case)
Future<List<File>> mymethodcall(List<Future<File>> attachments) {

    return CompositeFuture.all(ltol(attachments)).compose(files -> {
      // Note we're reading the result of the .all call in the compose
      List<File> mb = new ArrayList<>();
      files.list().stream().forEach(o -> {

        // Do whatever you need to do here with the results but they'll likely
        // need to be cast (to File, in this case).
        mb.add((File) o);
      });
      return Future.succeededFuture(mb);
    });
  }
```

The important step is getting your `List<Future<T>` into a `List<Future>`, **if you need to**.  I did it by gross brute force in the static method above.